# mysqli stores php variable not value

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

This is driving me nuts.  I am using the jQuery image upload and crop from 
http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/

I am using a modified version of the suggestion on here to store the file location in a MySQL database.  The mod is that I use INSERT on a table it works great except one thing, the 'owner' variable $id is being stored as $id and not as the value of $id.  I can echo the value if $id on each $_POST so I know it's there.

I am pretty sure my syntax is correct but I don't understand why it is doing this.

```
    $cropped = resizeThumbnailImage($thumb_image_location, $large_image_location,$w,$h,$x1,$y1,$scale);
    //connect to the database
    include 'config.php';
    // check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
    } 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `photos` (`id`,`owner`,`url`) VALUES ('id','".$id."','".$thumb_image_location."')";
    // Performs the $sql query on the server to insert the values
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $conn->close();}
//Reload the page again to view the thumbnail
header("location:".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
exit();
```

The first line is 246 and the last 3 are the orginal 247-250.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Ok, I don't know if this is my brain fart or an issue with PHP or a bit of both. I have $id assigned from the _SESSION variable in the header of each page AND (having forgotten that) I was passing $id as _POST data (same value). Once I cut out the _POST data passing and just pulled the _SESSION variable it works fine. But assigning a variable multiple times shouldn't be an issue, should it?

Comment: Is the string that shows up in your database "$id" or just "id"? If it's "id" that probably means that $id isn't getting set and PHP is falling back to interpreting it as a string. If it's "$id", the only thing I can think of that would cause that is having $id inside single quotes (while not nested inside double quotes), and that doesn't appear to be happening in your code.

Comment: What do you get if you echo $id right before the $sql = line?

Comment: Octern, the owner field is populated with $id.

Comment: Tim, echo shows the value of $id, I have it echoed at the top of each page for debugging.

Comment: Have you tried echoing it right before that $sql = statement to verify it isn't getting screwed up somewhere after the top of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the query line needs to be like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `photos` (`id`,`owner`,`url`) VALUES ('id','$id','$thumb_image_location')";
```

your syntax works fine too, as seen [here](http://codepad.org/Yac5JOxy)

this is how my syntax works, [here](http://codepad.org/06qupQQZ)

**Note:** both work the same, so still trying to figure out what's wrong in OP's code.

Comment: That way stores $id and not the value but the url still works.

Comment: This looks like it should be exactly equivalent to the query the OP is using, though it does require less eye-burning quote-tracking (unless I'm failing at said counting).

Comment: yeah, i just tested mine first, and then the OP's :), hence put both out there.

Comment: @Neilaka.Duckie, i tested both syntaxes, both work fine, as shown in my answer.